# jQuerys prop() method returns wrong id

Tags: jquery, forms, input, prop

when I've an input with name="id" within a form, the prop('id') method returns the input element instead of the id as string:

HTML

```
<form id="testform">
    <input name="id">
</form>
```

JS

```
var $form = $('#testform');

var wrongId = $form.prop('id');
var correctId = $form.attr('id');

alert(wrongId); // alerts the html input element
alert(correctId); // alerts the id testform
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

I've prepared a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zosu17se/

thanks and best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you've named the input `id`, and a name or ID of inputs, selects and other "form elements" are attached to the parent form as properties of the form for easier access, so `form.id` is the input, not the elements id.

Do **not** name the input `id` or any other property you might want to access, and the problem is solved.

Example of strange code caused by this

```js
var form = window.test; // note that element ID's are also attached to the global scope

form.id.value = 'test';
form.value.value = 'test more';
form.selectedIndex.value = '2';
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <input name="id">
  <input name="value">
  
  <select id="selectedIndex">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```